# Setting DropDownList Server Control Using jQuery Doesn't Change SelectedValue

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am running into an issue where I set the value of a dropdownlist (asp.net server control) using jQuery, but it doesn't change the selectedvalue upon postback.  The control is not databound, so I don't believe the issue has anything to do with the change being overwritten.  The control is inside a WizardControl, which I also don't think has anything to do with the issue.  On the client side everything works as expected.

Here is my code:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="MilitaryBackgroundSelect" ClientIDMode="Static">
    <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="" Selected="True" />                        
    <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="YES, IN THE ARMED FORCES" Value="1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="YES, IN THE RESERVES" Value="2" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="YES, IN THE NATIONAL GUARD" Value="3" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="REFUSED" Value="-7" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="DON'T KNOW" Value="-8" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="MISSING DATA" Value="-9" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I am setting the dropdownlist on the client side using this code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
      $('#MilitaryBackgroundSelect').val("1");
 });
```

NOTE:  I set the clientidmode to static on the dropdownlist, so I have no issue interacting with it using jQuery.  Below is the HTML rendered, notice the id field:

```
<select name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainContentNested$AHHQ_DataEntryWizard$MilitaryBackgroundSelect" 
id="MilitaryBackgroundSelect">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option selected="selected" value="0">No</option>
    <option value="1">YES, IN THE ARMED FORCES</option>
    <option value="2">YES, IN THE RESERVES</option>
    <option value="3">YES, IN THE NATIONAL GUARD</option>
    <option value="-7">REFUSED</option>
    <option value="-8">DON&#39;T KNOW</option>
    <option value="-9">MISSING DATA</option>
</select>
```

Comment: In your aspx you've given an ID of "MilitaryBackgroundSelect" but in the jQuery you've called "ActiveDutySelect"... Are you sure your code is what you think it is?

Comment: Is your dropdown ID MilitaryBackgroundSelect or ActiveDutySelect?

Comment: Does the selection occur correctly on the client side?  If you set `AutoPostback` to `true`, does a postback occur on that DDL?

Comment: I put the wrong snippet of code, should be fixed now.

Comment: Adding Autopostback=true didn't change anything

Comment: @Wade73 It wasn't meant to change functionality, but it should have caused a postback when your ready hit (assuming the current value was not -1).  Can you confirm whether or not the postback occurred?

Comment: @Chad, please I make typos, the issue is NOT I repeat the id of the control, but the fact the change is not being posted back to the server.

Comment: Why the -1 to my question?

Comment: @JTorres I did not get a postback

Comment: @Wade73 when you post code you should do your best to make sure that it is syntactically correct prior to posting here.  When we find obvious problems that will cause the issue you are seeing we point them out.

Comment: Chad, I appreciate that, but as I pointed out several times in the body of my question, the issue is not the id of the control and it works just fine.  I am human and I do make mistakes.

Comment: @Wade73 - How do you know if you can not get it to post back.  Have you tried using a value of an index in range?  See what happens when you try .val(3)  With all the problems here I suspect you have a syntax problem until you can get a successful result.

Comment: @Chad I am watching the post through Fiddler and the control is never posted back.  I will try the index.

Comment: @wade73 - So the Control is not even in the Form object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, changing a dropdownlist using javascript doesn't trigger the updated control being posted back to the server (verified using fiddler2).  I am not sure why that would be, but there are some workarounds.

1. You can use a hidden field and when you change the dropdownlists value, you will also update the hidden value.  Here is a snippet I used to do that using jQuery:

   ```
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
         $('#dropdownelelement').change(function() {

          var elementID = $(this).attr("id");

          $("#" + elementID + "hidden").val($(this).val());

          });
   ```

   });
2. I looked into the [ASP.Net AJAX Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/) combobox control.  It works similar to the approach above, since when it is rendered to the client browser, it uses a hidden field to store its values.

In the end I had to reject both approaches due to how complex some of the logic was for which field to enable or disable based on the user input.  I put the code into an update panel, enabled autopostback on the controls which drove the enabled logic, and used validator controls to enforce my logic.  It causes the nasty screen flicker, but the code is much simplier.

Thanks to all who tried to help.

Answer (score 2):

since you are running it on the server you have to use

```
<%= someObject.ClientID %>
```

instead of the regular id

Also make sure that the jquery code to set the dropdown is within

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
      $('#militaryBackgroundSelect').val(-1);
 });
```

Maybe on a later verson of jquery you could use

```
 $("#militaryBackgroundSelect option[value='-1']").attr("selected", "selected");
```

Comment: DWolf is right, asp.net assigns new ids to server-side controls. Although it looks like the jquery code you posted doesn't match the asp.net control you posted so this wouldn't work regardless. Careless mistake possibly?

Comment: I set the clientid to static, so jQuery finds and modifies the control just fine.

Comment: He set ClientIDMode to Static, so the rendered control will have just the ID specified without any of the added cruft that webforms adds otherwise.

Comment: well regardless, the jquery id doesnt match the drop down list id

Comment: It was a mistake, it is now fixed.  As I said, setting the drop down was not the problem in jQuery, so it is not the issue.

Comment: @DWolf I left that out, but the code is in the ready function.