# dropdownlist not changed SelectedValue on server side

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have an dropdownlist

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNationality" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
```

in document ready I set

```
ddlNationality.selectedIndex = -1;
```

for show to user nothing selected

After I change value and click some button on server side my selected value is alway zero, after I change selected value in javascript I check if selected values is changed and all i ok, but o server side selected value not changed,.. how to proceed?

I can to insert in this dropdownlist first item with no value and no text, but I want to have in dropdownlist only my values without clear field

Comment: I found some workaround using hidden field [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14073523/setting-dropdownlist-server-control-using-jquery-doesnt-change-selectedvalue

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are missing attribute `AutoPostBack="true"`

Comment: if I set autopostback to true, then after every change of dropdownlist value the page is refresh

Comment: you have to notify server somehow, if you don't like the old page refresh, then maybe use ajax?

Comment: if I don't set ddlNationality.selectedIndex = -1; in javascript all works OK

Answer (score 0):

When you are not posting back and changing the value of dropdownlist in client, asp.net cannot be informed about it.

Create a hidden field:

```
<input id="MyHiddenField" type="hidden" runat="server" class="my-hidden-field" value="" />
```

Whenever you are changing the value in client set the value to hidden field:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select.my-ddl-class').on('change', function () {
        $('.my-hidden-field').val(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);
    });
});
```

Then, on the code-behind instead of getting the DropDownList selected value, read hidden field value:

```
selectedValue = int.Parse(MyHiddenField.Value);
```